# Adding section on button in visualforce

Tags: visualforce, pageblocksection

I have 3 same sections in visualforce page. Users will have 3 of this section minimal to fill out. But what i want to make is button on which i will add new section, same as others. Because user may need 20 of this section, maybe 30. But some of them maybe need only 3. I don't want to take a lot of space, so i want to make some button '+' on which i will be available to add as much sections as i want. Can someone help me? ( image)

[image]

Comment: Include your current code please.

Answer (score 1):

You can output an `apex:pageBlockSection` per object, starting with 3 created in your controller and then having a button that adds one at a time and re-renders the page block to show the new additions:

```
<apex:page controller="...">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:repeat value="{!contacts}" var="c">
                <apex:pageBlockSection title="Authorized Person">
                    <apex:outputField value="{!c.Name}"/>
                    ...
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: How to make that button?

Comment: @IgorStosic See these examples http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=apex%3AcommandButton.